# Clarification on where testing falls in the pipeline

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-pipelines

I was reading something that made me question if I'm implementing testing in my pipeline correctly.

I currently have it setup like the following:

- Local feature branch for a microservice pushed to remote
- PR request to merge feature request into `testing` branch for microservice
- Accepted and merged
- Triggers CI/CD pipeline:

  - First, a Linux VM is created
  - The microservice is deployed to the VM
  - The tests are run for the microservice
  - If all testing passes, it builds the Docker image and pushes it to the container registry
  - The deployment stage then pulls the image and deploys to the Kubernetes cluster

My questions are the following:

- The dev should be testing locally, but should testing automatically happen when the PR is submitted?
- Should I be building the Docker image first, creating a running container of the image and testing that (that is after all what is getting deployed)?

In other words, is the flow:

1. Build app -> test -> if passes, build image -> deploy
2. Build image -> test -> if passes, deploy
3. Build app -> run certain tests -> if passes, build image -> run more tests -> deploy

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Generally, the bulk of your tests should be unit tests that can be run in isolation without relying on a deployment. Every test that's feasible to run during your build and deployment process should run, as soon as possible, and result in not proceeding with future steps if any tests fail.

Comment: option 1 is quicker in identifying the failures, but option 2 tests the build image process too and you can be more sure that what passes the tests inside the container is fine. I go with option 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things I'd rearrange here.

As @DanielMann notes in a comment, your service should have a substantial set of unit tests.  These don't require running in a container and don't have dependencies on any external resources; you might be able to use mock implementations of service clients, or alternate implementations like SQLite as an in-process database.  Once your CI system sees a commit, before it builds an image, it should run these unit tests.

You should then run as much of the test sequence as you can against the pull request.  (If the integration tests fail *after* you've merged to the main branch, your build is broken, and that can be problematic if you need an emergency fix.)  Especially you can build a Docker image from the PR branch.  Depending on how your system is set up you may be able to test that directly; either with an alternate plain-Docker environment, or in a dedicated Kubernetes namespace, or using a local Kubernetes environment like minikube or kind.

Absolutely test the same Docker image you will be running in production.

In summary, I'd rearrange your workflow as:

1. Local feature branch for a microservice pushed to remote
2. PR request to merge feature request into `testing` branch for microservice

   1. Triggers CI pipeline:
   2. Run unit tests (without Docker)
   3. Builds a Docker image (and optionally pushes to a registry)
   4. Deploy to some test setup and run integration tests (with Docker)
3. Accepted and merged

   1. Triggers CI/CD pipeline:
   2. Runs unit tests (without Docker)
   3. Builds a Docker image and pushes it
   4. Deploy to the production Kubernetes environment

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and clarification. I have a lot of reading and research I need to do on this. As I'm envisioning this structure overall, it is almost fork like: each microservice has its own pipeline and unit testing (in my case Django API, React `/` and React `/admin`); if those pass, I need to build the Docker image and deploy in some way that such that `/api` and `/`, or `/api` and `/admin`, can now talk to one another for integration testing (`/` and `/admin` don't really interact).

Comment: I put this graphic together to try to wrap my brain around this better. Still need to wrap my brain around the integration / BDD testing portion. Input from anyone would be appreciated as I iron this process out: https://imgur.com/a/6eMnVcd.

Comment: I read this and your other answers where you are stressing on point that unit test does not require running in a container and don't have dependencies on any external resources.

My doubt is as container is what is going to be deployed after all, shouldn't we build a image and then run a container, and inside it run tests (We can stop the server that got run in container when we started the container before running tests with docker exec)?

This will test if npm install worked correctly and we will be more sure that docker image got build correctly.

Comment: Using same docker container that runs in the production for testing minimises the difference among testing and production environment.

Comment: The better-maintained code I work on has an isolated unit-test suite, so I can run hundreds of unit tests in a couple of seconds, without any container dependencies.  This makes it very easy to run the tests, make a code change, and iterate.  We also have an integration-test suite, which does build an image, deploy it, and runs tests, but it takes a minimum of 15 minutes to run; very bad for iteration, very hard to debug, but much closer to the real environment.  The services where the unit tests take minutes to run are hard to keep focus.